# how do i handle every route possible with a react router at the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

Following the [readme in the react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/overview.md):

```
var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="inbox" handler={Inbox}/>
    <Route name="calendar" handler={Calendar}/>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Dashboard}/>
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

Being extremely fresh to node and a reputable front end js framework please excuse the noobish question..

How is it best to handle the routes at the server?

I mean, what happens when someone lands on `/calendar`, do i have to accommodate for the route at the client in the react code and at the server in express routes, or should there be a wildcard route at express. IE someone lands on `/calendar`, should express deliever the html for `/` and allow react to handle the rest?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how it works specifically with react-router, but typically with client-side routing you serve up just the main index file from the server and then the client handles the route.

With Express you can setup a route that always serves your main index file (and in turn your client-side). On my site I use AngularJS for the routing, and the only route I have outside of middleware is

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

From there the client handles all routes.

Comment: right ok cool thanks. To help preload information is it then a good idea to try and catch the requested paths or is that just not the idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use React Router to render *all* routes on both sides.

On the server side, if you're using Express or similar, this usually means creating some middleware which will use React Router to handle the incoming request, instead of using your server-side lib's own routing. There's a minimal example and explanation of this in this answer:

- [Client Routing (using react-router) and Server-Side Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28558545/6760)

For a more advanced example, I have some Express middleware which also handles data fetching, page title generation and bootstrapping on the client, which is documented here, with links to relevant source:

- https://github.com/insin/isomorphic-lab/tree/master#express-middleware-source