# React Router always displaying IndexRoute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, ecmascript-6, react-router

This is my main app file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { browserHistory, Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

// Components
import Main from './components/core/Main.component';
import NotFound from './components/core/NotFound.component';
import About from './components/About.component';
import TeaTimer from './components/TeaTimer.component';

// App css
require('style!css!sass!applicationStyles');

render(
    (<div>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route component={Main} path="/">
          <IndexRoute component={TeaTimer} />
          <Route component={About} path="/about"/>
        </Route>
        <Route component={NotFound} path="*"/>
      </Router>
    </div>),
    document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

This is my Main component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    )
  }
}

Main.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.object
}

export default Main;
```

This is my express server setup:

```
var express = require('express');

// Create our app
var app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(function (req, res, next){
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https') {
    res.redirect('http://' + req.hostname + req.url);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Express server is up on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Now when I open the browser and go to `http://localhost:3000` I get the TeaTimer component. Same for `http://localhost:3000/#/`, same for `http://localhost:3000/#/about`, same for an undefined route - `http://localhost:3000/#/sdnaipwnda[j`.

But when I go to `http://localhost:3000/about` I get:

> Cannot GET /about

What am I doing wrong?

If you need more info please ask and I will add it to the question, or checkout this [git repo](https://github.com/Shooshte/tea-timer-rewrite).

Comment: You need this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30720330/4355342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this one is straightforward. You're simply using the wrong history. You need `hashHistory` if you want to have hash-based, i.e. `/#/about` and such, routes.

`import {Router, hashHistory} from 'react-router'
...
<Router history={hashHistory}>
...`

If you DON'T want a hash-based history, but would rather like regular-looking URL's, like `/about` and such, then you DO need `browserHistory`. However, in this case you MUST make sure that your web server serves the same `index.html` for all route-like URL's. This is explained in the `react-router`' [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory). You need to add something like this towards the end of your express server's routing configuration:

`// handle every other route with index.html, which will contain
// a script tag to your application's JavaScript file(s).
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})`

The above code assumes that your index.html file lies in `public/`, so you might need to change the arguments to `path.resolve`.

I actually prefer returning index.html only for URL's that don't have an extension. This way you prevent your index.html being served as a .png or .js whenever the requested resource is missing and you get a meaningful 404 instead.

`app.get('*', function (request, response){
  if (request.path.match(/\/[^\/.]*$/)) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
  }
})`

Answer (score 0):

remove `/` from path

```
<Route component={About} path="about"/>
```

remove

```
Main.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

anyway children are passed as props by default

Comment: another it might be from proptypes, if not I am sorry for not being able to help

Comment: nah, this does not solve it as well. it's weird because I am not getting any erros at all...Thanks for trying :)

Comment: I am not that much familiar with Express, but I think this might help
https://github.com/Remchi/reddice/blob/master/server/index.js

Answer (score 0):

no need to have / inside about path.

```
render(
    (<div>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route component={Main} path="/">
          <IndexRoute component={TeaTimer} />
          <Route component={About} path="about" />
        </Route>
        <Route component={NotFound} path="*" />
      </Router>
    </div>),
    document.querySelector('#app')
);
```