# react-router : run is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing, flux

A Egghead tutorial teaches it like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var routes = require('./config/routes');

Router.run(routes, function(Root){
  React.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Yet I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Router.run is not a function

note:
I've already updated `react-router` to the recent version.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Since the release of React Router v1.0, the `run` method has been removed, these breaking changes are documented in the upgrade guide. Your code would roughly translate to this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Router>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

> https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/832c42946c874fe56ffde0066b1088054311cb98/CHANGES.md

Comment: Course! Curious though, does babel-loader somehow keep it working? Cause I updated the tutorials react-router to the most current version ( react-router@1.0.0-rc1) and their example still works with run.

Comment: maybe forgot to restart the watch/build process?

Comment: Upgrade info is now on the [changelog](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/832c42946c874fe56ffde0066b1088054311cb98/CHANGES.md)

Comment: React.render() is deprecated. Use ReactDOM instead.