# webpack react router unable to navigate child pages

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am using `react-router 2.0` and `webpack`. I have the following code in my app.js. When I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/` I get the `Main` page. But if I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/about` I was expecting `about` page to take full screen. But I get an error saying `Cannot GET /about`. Should I do something on the webpack config to allow these routes?

```
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
       <Route path="/" component={Main}>
         <Route path="about" component={About} />
         <Route path="help" component={Help} />
       </Route>          
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Your code above seems to be correct. Nearly identical to the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) as well.

Comment: yes, not sure whats wrong on the server side, cant workout what to do to allow these routes.

Comment: How are you implementing your Router though? Do you have a `Router.run` somewhere?

Comment: Do I need Router.run, thought this is all that is required according to their main page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682854/react-router-run-is-not-a-function, its pre 1.x way of routing.

Comment: I've only seen that error message on pre v1. If you are certain you have the latest version then I don't know what to suggest :/

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean. I had this issue as well but solved it by using browsersync and `connect-history-api-fallback`.

Create a file called `srcServer.js` and add something like this (of course install all the dependencies required):

```
// Require Browsersync along with webpack and middleware for it
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import historyApiFallback from 'connect-history-api-fallback';

const webpackConfig = {
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    noInfo: true, 
    entry: './src/index',
    target:  'web', 
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist', 
        publicPath: '',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [], //[your array of plugins],
    module: {
        loaders: [] //[your array of loaders],
    }
}
const bundler = webpack(webpackConfig);

// Run Browsersync and use middleware for Hot Module Replacement
browserSync({
    server: {
        baseDir: 'src',

        middleware: [
            historyApiFallback(),  // <-- the key to loading a route in the url directly (without navigating to it first)
            webpackDevMiddleware(bundler, {
                // Dev middleware can't access config, so we provide publicPath
                publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
                stats: {colors: true},
                noInfo: true
            }),
            // bundler should be the same as above
            webpackHotMiddleware(bundler)
        ]
    },

    // no need to watch '*.js' here, webpack will take care of it for us,
    // including full page reloads if HMR won't work
    files: [
        'src/*.html'
    ]
});
```

Then you can add an npm script to your package.json, lets say `npm run start`:

```
  "scripts": {
     "start": "babel-node srcServer.js",
  },
```

And this should serve your files with `connect-history-api-fallback` which will allow you to directly load and reload `http://localhost:3000/about`

Answer (score -1):

It looks that your server is not prepared to handle the router URLs. You are using `browserHistory` so you need to [configure your server](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/Histories.md#configuring-your-server) to return your `index.html` for all your route URLs.

From the docs:

> An express app might look like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
const app = express()

// serve static assets normally
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

// handle every other route with index.html, which will contain
// a script tag to your application's JavaScript file(s).
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port)
console.log("server started on port " + port)
```

> If you're using nginx, use the try_files directive:

```
server {
  ...
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't read what the author was asking and you just copied and pasted a solution from another blog post.