# router.run deprecated convert to latest code

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, redux

I picked up a sample from somewhere trying to learn react redux nodejs unfortunately i studied that and done a lot of changes in the existing code. Later i realised that the code that i picked uses very old version of react. I have fixed all the problems except to write the following part without disrupting the functionality in server.jsx

```
 app.use((req, res) => {
  delete process.env.BROWSER;
  const logger = store => next => action => {
     let result = next(action);
     return result;
  };

  const location = createLocation(req.url);
  const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
  let createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware, logger)(createStore);
  const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);

  Router.run(routes, location, (err, routeState) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    if (!routeState) return res.status(404).end('404');
    const InitialComponent = (
      <Provider store={store}>
        {() =>
          <Router {...routeState} />
        }
      </Provider>
    );

    const componentHTML = React.renderToString(InitialComponent);
    const initialState = store.getState();
    const HTML = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
          <title>BookMyDoc</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/react-select.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
          <script type="application/javascript">
            window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(initialState)};
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="react-view">${componentHTML}</div>
          <script type="application/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>
          <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
    `
    res.end(HTML);
  });
});
```

Please help me do the same thing in the updated version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682854/react-router-run-is-not-a-function.

Comment: @BradBumbalough, yes but if you see the HTML is rendered right from here so i need someone who could help me fix this code. The question however equivalent but is at code conversion level.

Comment: I don't think it matters actually.. the issue is `router.Run` is no longer the means to trigger server rendering. You use `match` instead. What happens after that would be the same.

Comment: @BradBumbalough if you could do the equivalent code in answers would be great. Sorry from a newbee like me.

Comment: No offence but I don't have time to rewrite your code for your :) This doc should help... https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md